# Disabling headers in BrowseFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tv, leanback

I need to disable headers in **BrowseFragment**, and add to the **ArrayObjectAdapter** card. When I do a `setHeadersState(HEADERS_DISABLED)` application crushes. If I run `setHeadersState(HEADERS_DISABLED)` method later, for example in `onLoadFinished`, the application does not crash, but the header bar immediately visible and then hidden, not every time an item is displayed in the adapter.

**MainFragment.class**

```
 public class MainFragment extends BrowseFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Module>> {
        private static final int MODULES_LOADER_ID = 100;
        private ArrayObjectAdapter mRowsAdapter;
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            setupUIElements();
            setupRowAdapter();
            setupListeners();
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(MODULES_LOADER_ID, null, this);
        }
            private void setupUIElements() {
            setTitle(getActivity().getString(R.string.app_name));
            setBadgeDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.title, getActivity().getTheme()));
            setHeadersTransitionOnBackEnabled(false);
            setBrandColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.fastlane_background));
            setHeadersState(HEADERS_DISABLED);
        }
            private void setupRowAdapter() {
            mRowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new ListRowPresenter());
            setAdapter(mRowsAdapter);
        }
            private void setupListeners() {
            setOnItemViewSelectedListener(new ItemViewSelectedListener());
            setOnItemViewClickedListener(new ItemViewClickedListener());
        }
            private void loadModules(List<Module> modules) {
            ArrayObjectAdapter listRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new ModulesCardPresenter());
            for (Module module : modules) {
                listRowAdapter.add(module);
            }
            HeaderItem header = new HeaderItem(0, "Меню");
            mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(header, listRowAdapter));
        }
        @Override
        public Loader<List<Module>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            switch (id) {
                case MODULES_LOADER_ID:
                    return new ModulesLoader(getActivity());
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Module>> loader, List<Module> data) {
            switch (loader.getId()) {
                case MODULES_LOADER_ID:
                    loadModules(data);
                    break;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Module>> loader) {
        }
        static class ModulesLoader extends SimpleAsyncTaskLoader<List<Module>> {
            public ModulesLoader(Context context) {
                super(context);
            }
            @Override
            public List<Module> loadInBackground() {
                Call<Modules> mCall = ServiceHolder.getService()
                        .getModules(Constants.GET_MODULES_REQUEST);
                try {
                    return mCall.execute().body().getModules();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
                }
            }
        }
        private final class ItemViewSelectedListener implements OnItemViewSelectedListener {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(Presenter.ViewHolder itemViewHolder, Object item,
                                       RowPresenter.ViewHolder rowViewHolder, Row row) {
            }
        }
        private final class ItemViewClickedListener implements OnItemViewClickedListener {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(Presenter.ViewHolder itemViewHolder, Object item,
                                      RowPresenter.ViewHolder rowViewHolder, Row row) {
                }
        }
```

**Log:**

```
08-18 16:06:08.331 29647-29647/ E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: , PID: 29647
    **java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Fragment.getView()' on a null object reference**
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Fragment.getView()' on a null object reference**
    at android.support.v17.leanback.app.BrowseFragment.onStart(BrowseFragment.java:1511)
    at android.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2244)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1002)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1130)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:1958)
    at android.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:163)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6274)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) </code>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have `setHeadersState(HEADERS_DISABLED)` in my fragment `onCreate()` method. It looks like you have yours in `onActivityCreated()`. You should try moving it. Let me know if that works.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHeadersState(HEADERS_DISABLED)
}
```

Comment: I moved `setHeadersState(HEADERS_DISABLED)` to `onCreate()`, but nothing has changed. Application crash on startup with the same error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method android.view.View android.app.Fragment.getView() on a null object reference`

Comment: Are you sure it's your `setHeadersState()` that is causing the crash? I would suggestion commenting everything else out except for that line (including the loader) and see if it still crashes. I have a fragment with nothing but `setHeaders` being called in `onCreate` and I haven't seen a crash.

Comment: I tried to leave only the method `setHeadersState(HEADERS_DISABLED)` in `onCreate()` problem still exists. As soon as I transfer the execution of the method `setHeadersState(HEADERS_DISABLED)`  later (ie in `onLoadFinished`) - it works great!

Comment: What version of Leanback are you currently using?

Comment: It was 24.1.1. I updated to 24.2.0, but the problem remained.

Comment: How are you adding `MainFragment` to your view? Are you adding it via XML or are are you using the fragment manager?

Comment: `MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
            getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();`

Comment: Okay this shouldn't matter, but can you try declaring your fragment in your [layout XML](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html#AddInLayout) instead of using a transaction?

Comment: Instead transactions fragment, I put fragment in activity_main.xml. Nothing changed. The same error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it'll be useful to you
[code.google.com issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=214795)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately there is only a problem, but no solution :(

Answer (score 0):

As [Viktor Dolgalyov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4587231/viktor-dolgalyov) has [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39038739/3591480), there is a bug filed. [#214795](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=214795) which is followed by [#223942](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223942) where there is an official reply that this will be fixed around December.